# Matrix ring isomorphisms of different sizes

Tags: ra.rings-and-algebras, noncommutative-algebra, noncommutative-rings

Do there exist (unital, associative, noncommutative) rings $R$ and $S$, where $\mathbb{M}_2(R)\cong \mathbb{M}_3(S)$, but these matrix rings are **not** isomorphic to $\mathbb{M}_6(T)$ for any ring $T$?

Comment: I don’t have time just now to write a full answer, but doesn’t this follow from Bergman’s theorem that every monoid is the monoid of finitely generated projective modules for some ring unless it obviously isn’t?

Comment: @JeremyRickard Ah, so we take the commutative monoid generated by two elements $a,b$, subject to the single relation $a+a=b+b+b$.  Taking $R$ to be the endomorphism ring of the projective module corresponding to $a$, and taking $S$ to be the endomorphism ring of the projective module corresponding to $b$, we are done (because, clearly, no element $c$ exists with $6c=2a=3b$).

Comment: Or $(\mathbb{N}\setminus\{1\},+)$, as some people prefer to call that monoid.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

If $\Lambda$ is a ring, then the isomorphism classes of finitely generated
projective $\Lambda$-modules form a commutative monoid $(A,+)$, with
$[P]+[Q]=[P\oplus Q]$. This monoid contains a distinguished element $I$: namely,
the class $[\Lambda]$ of the free module of rank one.

This monoid $(A,I)$ with distinguished element satisfies two obvious properties: that
$$(\forall x,y\in A),\,\, x+y=0\Rightarrow x=y=0,$$
and that
$$(\forall x\in A)(\exists y\in A)(\exists n\in\mathbb{N}),\,\,x+y=nI.$$

$\Lambda$ is a $d\times d$ matrix ring if and only if $I$ is divisible by $d$
in the monoid $A$: if $\Lambda\cong P^{d}$ as right modules, then
$\Lambda\cong\mathbb{M}_{d}\left(\operatorname{End}_{\Lambda}(P)\right)$, and if
$\Lambda\cong\mathbb{M}_{d}(\Gamma)$ with matrix units $e_{ij}$, then
$\Lambda\cong e_{11}(\Lambda)\oplus\cdots\oplus e_{dd}(\Lambda)$ as right
modules, where $e_{ij}$ induces an isomorphism $e_{jj}(\Lambda)\cong e_{ii}(\Lambda)$.

In Theorems 6.2 and 6.4 of

*Bergman, George M.*, [**Coproducts and some universal ring constructions**](https://doi.org/10.2307/1997247), Trans. Am. Math. Soc. 200, 33-88 (1974),

George Bergman proved that every $(A,I)$ satisfying the conditions above
is isomorphic to that coming from some ring $\Lambda$.

Taking $A=(\mathbb{N}\setminus\{1\},+)$ and $I=6$, the distinguished element $I$
is divisible by $2$ and by $3$, but not by $6$, so the ring $\Lambda$ is a
$2\times2$ matrix ring and a $3\times3$ matrix ring, but not a $6\times6$ matrix
ring.

Comment: This is a really nice answer and shows why full answers are better than comments.  I didn’t see from the comment how to tell that it is not a 6x6 matrix algebra for any ring but now it is clear.